# What exactly is RichWidgets/Popup_Upload.aspx

Tags: asp.net

I have detected `RichWidgets/Popup_Upload` page in one of the tests and we can send a POST request to the webpage. And when I looked at it online, I saw that there are thousands of domains using this RichWidget.

In order to understand if we can upload malicious files with this upload functionality, I just want to install it locally and try that but can not find this `Popup_Upload` endpoint anywhere or any blogs about it. I found the following github repo and online demo of the widgets but there is no upload function in this repo.

Links:
https://github.com/richwidgets/richwidgets
http://www.richwidgets.io/

Is there anyone who knows what this is and where can I find the source files to read?

Answer (score 0):

RichWidgets/Popup_Upload.aspx is actually one of the widgets that is used in the OutSystems Platform.

Reference:
https://andrefmota.outsystemscloud.com/RichWidgetsSample/PopupUpload.aspx

Comment: So is there any way to install it easily such as a docker container or something like that?